# Travis CI PyPI deploy interpreter

Tags: python, travis-ci, distutils, pypi

My setup.py contains `scripts=["package-name"]` parameter and .travis.yml is:

```
deploy:
  provider: pypi
  distributions: "sdist bdist bdist_wheel"
  docs_dir: docs
  user: ...
  password:
    secure: ...
```

But, when package is deployed to PyPI, shebang lines in scripts are converted into something like: `/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/bin/python`, which, of course, is bad interpreter on target machine.

If I deploy from hand, I can use `python setup.py -e '/usr/bin/env python' sdist upload`, but how can I bypass this parameter in Travis?